# rails 3 form remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, remote-forms

I am write:

```
<%= form_for(current_user, :remote => true) do %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag t("language") %>: 
    <%= select_tag "language", options_for_select([["Русский", "rus"], ["English", "eng"]]) %>
  </p>

  <p><%= submit_tag t "options.save" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Inspector:
http://deeflow.com/changer/inspect.png

Content:
http://deeflow.com/changer/content.png

But, value in db doesn't updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_for(current_user, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :language, t("language") %>: 
    <%= f.select :language, options_for_select([["Русский", "rus"], ["English", "eng"]]) %>
  </p>

  <p><%= f.submit t "options.save" %></p>
<% end %>
```

Notice the variable `|f|` and change of `label_tag, select_tag and submit_tag` to `f.label, f.select and f.submit`

In rails `form_for` and corresponding `form_buider` object(`|f|`) are used to group values under a common key, which rails can understand. `*_tag` helpers are generally used to pass unrelated parameters.

Comment: `Form Dataview URL encoded
utf8:✓
_method:put
authenticity_token:epPcqZuTWLM4qwdgTXfbuuDLj64Pn2q2mzTWLB3AO2E=
user%5Blanguage%5D:eng
commit:Save` incorect : user%5Blanguage%5D:eng

Comment: have you checked that your current_user is not nil?

Comment: #<User id: 1, email: "barthez.slavik@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$vOfBA2WhLIXyhweD3bXZSeEqJ240UPh85muJ47jEnH.w...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 14, current_sign_in_at: "2011-07-04 08:27:51", last_sign_in_at: "2011-07-03 21:39:38", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", created_at: "2011-07-01 15:43:04", updated_at: "2011-07-04 08:27:51", username: nil, password_salt: nil, password_hash: nil, avatar_url: nil, language: nil>